# How to run a .ts file w/ .ts file imports using ts-node?

Tags: typescript, ts-node

I'm writing a console script.
I have a folder structure like

```
/
/helper/methods.ts
/index.ts
```

Lets say methods.ts has a function "foo".

I'm running:

```
.\node_modules\.bin\ts-node.cmd index.ts
```

I want to do something like

```
import * as helpers from "./helper/methods";
helpers.foo(<args>);
```

But it says "/helper/methods.ts" is not a module.

I can load the file by doing this:

```
import './helper/methods";
```

But if I try to call "foo" I get "foo is not defined."

Comment: Could you share some of the _./helper/methods_ contents?

Comment: Have you tried using `const helpers = require('./helpers/foo');` instead of the import statement ?